# Does the CAF receiver support Live DAI?

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk, caf-receiver-sdk

We have a custom CAF receiver that has both VOD and Live content. Currently our VOD content uses VMAP and we would like to use DAI for live content. I'm not finding much documentation on using DAI with the built in CAF ad functionality.

The CAF [ad examples](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/ad_breaks) seem to be geared towards VOD content. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/cast/dai/quickstart) that I have found relating to DAI and cast appears to be outdated (v2 instead of v3).

Does anyone have any more information on using a DAI live stream with the CAF receiver?

Is it possible to get the cue points / duration from a DAI live stream to be able to use the [server-side ad stitching example](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/ad_breaks#server-side_ad_stitching)?

Answer (score 0):

Just an update: the DAI feature will be launched later this quarter, most likely early Q4.